# Memory leak error in implementation of merge sort in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to write a program in C that performs the merge sort algorithm on an array of integers. The code appears to run correctly and produces the right output, but when I run valgrind, I am informed of memory leak errors.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int *merge(int len_1, int len_2, int *arr1, int *arr2);
int *merge_sort(int len, int *arr);

int main(void){
    int arr[] = {10, 3, 7, 5, 11, 16, 23, 14};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int *result = merge_sort(len, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("%i\n", result[i]);
    }

    free(result);
    return 0;
}

int *merge(int len_1, int len_2, int *arr1, int *arr2){

    //Allocating memory for the output array
    int *result = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (len_1 + len_2));

    //Initialising a pointer for both arrays
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;

    //Sorting the values
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len_1 + len_2; i++){
        if ((p1 < len_1) && (p2 >= len_2 || arr1[p1] <= arr2[p2])){
            result[i] = arr1[p1];
            p1++;
        }
        else{
            result[i] = arr2[p2];
            p2++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int *merge_sort(int len, int *arr){

    //An array with one element is already sorted
    if (len == 1){
        return arr;
    }

    //Compute midpoint and allocate memory
    int midpoint = floor((float)len/2);
    int *left = (int *)malloc(midpoint * sizeof(int));
    int *right = (int *)malloc((len - midpoint) * sizeof(int));

    //Assign the correct values to the left and right subarrays
    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++){
        left[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len - midpoint; i++){
        right[i] = arr[midpoint + i];
    }

    //Sort the left and right subarrays
    int *left_sorted = merge_sort(midpoint, left);
    int *right_sorted = merge_sort(len - midpoint, right);

    //Merge the sorted subarrays
    int *sorted_array = merge(midpoint, len - midpoint, left_sorted, right_sorted);

    //Free memory
    free(left);
    free(right);

    return sorted_array;
}
```

And here is the report from valgrind:

```
==39891== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==39891== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==39891== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==39891== Command: ./merge_sort
==39891== 
3
5
7
10
11
14
16
23
==39891== 
==39891== HEAP SUMMARY:
==39891==     in use at exit: 64 bytes in 6 blocks
==39891==   total heap usage: 21 allocs, 15 frees, 192 bytes allocated
==39891== 
==39891== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==39891==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39891==    by 0x109387: merge (merge_sort.c:24)
==39891==    by 0x10932E: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:70)
==39891==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==39891==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==39891==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==39891== 
==39891== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 6
==39891==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39891==    by 0x109387: merge (merge_sort.c:24)
==39891==    by 0x10932E: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:70)
==39891==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==39891==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==39891==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==39891== 
==39891== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==39891==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39891==    by 0x109387: merge (merge_sort.c:24)
==39891==    by 0x10932E: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:70)
==39891==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==39891==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==39891==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==39891== 
==39891== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 6
==39891==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39891==    by 0x109387: merge (merge_sort.c:24)
==39891==    by 0x10932E: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:70)
==39891==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==39891==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==39891==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==39891== 
==39891== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==39891==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39891==    by 0x109387: merge (merge_sort.c:24)
==39891==    by 0x10932E: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:70)
==39891==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==39891==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==39891== 
==39891== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==39891==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39891==    by 0x109387: merge (merge_sort.c:24)
==39891==    by 0x10932E: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:70)
==39891==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==39891==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==39891== 
==39891== LEAK SUMMARY:
==39891==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 6 blocks
==39891==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==39891==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==39891==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==39891==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==39891== 
==39891== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==39891== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I think I have not freed some memory somewhere after using malloc, but I'm not sure where I should be freeing memory from. I free the memory allocated to result, but I don't see what else I could free?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I made the following adjustment to the `merge_sort` function:

```c
//Free memory
free(left);
free(right);
free(left_sorted);
free(right_sorted);
```

The valgrind report is now as follows:

```
==55558== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==55558== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==55558== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==55558== Command: ./merge_sort
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10934D: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:75)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb5180 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10933B: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:73)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109263: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:54)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109356: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:76)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb51d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109344: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:74)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109279: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:55)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10934D: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:75)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb5270 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10933B: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:73)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109263: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:54)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109356: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:76)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb52c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109344: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:74)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109279: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:55)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10934D: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:75)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb5450 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10933B: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:73)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109263: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:54)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109356: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:76)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb54a0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109344: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:74)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109279: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:55)
==55558==    by 0x109301: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:66)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10934D: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:75)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb5540 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x10933B: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:73)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109263: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:54)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
==55558== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109356: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:76)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Address 0x4bb5590 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==55558==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109344: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:74)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558==  Block was alloc'd at
==55558==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55558==    by 0x109279: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:55)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x109314: merge_sort (merge_sort.c:67)
==55558==    by 0x1091BD: main (merge_sort.c:11)
==55558== 
3
5
7
10
11
14
16
23
==55558== 
==55558== HEAP SUMMARY:
==55558==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==55558==   total heap usage: 21 allocs, 29 frees, 192 bytes allocated
==55558== 
==55558== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==55558== 
==55558== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==55558== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The code also no longer runs, displaying the following error in Bash:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It appears that adding those free() lines removed the memory leak error but now something else seems to have gone horribly wrong and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What happens with the memory that the recursive calls to `merge_sort` returns?

Comment: I think the problem is that whenever merge is called, memory is allocated to the temporary result, but then I'm not sure how to free this memory. If I freed it inside the merge function then it wouldn't be able to return anything.

Comment: After the call to `merge`, try e.g. `free(left_sorted)` and see what happens.

Comment: Unrelated but integer division will truncate.  Prefer that to `floor()`,

Comment: Ok, so this fixes the memory leak issue, but now the code doesn't function at all. I get the following error: free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped).

Comment: Don't cast the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a new section at the end, where you show how you incorporated the changes.

Comment: It might be better to use `size_t` rather than `int` for the length of the arrays in the function argument lists.  You then only have to deal with length 0 and 1 as special cases (the array is already sorted in both cases).  Otherwise you have to worry about negative lengths, somehow reporting an error, or maybe just deeming arrays with a negative number of elements as "already sorted" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal fix is to free `left_sorted` and `right_sorted` in `merge_sort()` if the recursive call allocated a new array  (i.e. `len > 1`).

It is easier to reason about heap allocations if `malloc()` and `free()` happens in the same function.

I refactored the code slightly to emphasize that heap allocated memory is a liability and I want to `free()` it as soon as possible.  It also lowers maximum memory usage.

While I appreciate the functional style (consider `const` for all array arguments you don't modify), could caller pass a suitable array into  `merge_sort()` so you only need 1 `malloc()` in `main()` instead of 22?

Prefer passing instead of a type of `sizeof`.

(Not fixed) Always check the return value of `malloc()`.

```
int *merge_sort(int len, int *arr) {
    if (len == 1)
        return arr;

    int midpoint = len / 2;
    int *left = malloc(sizeof *left * midpoint);
    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
        left[i] = arr[i];
    int *left_sorted = merge_sort(midpoint, left);

    int *right = malloc(sizeof *right * (len - midpoint));
    for (int i = 0; i < len - midpoint; i++)
        right[i] = arr[midpoint + i];
    int *right_sorted = merge_sort(len - midpoint, right);

    int *sorted_array = merge(midpoint, len - midpoint, left_sorted, right_sorted);
    if(midpoint > 1)
        free(left_sorted);
    if(len - midpoint > 1)
        free(right_sorted);
    free(left);
    free(right);

    return sorted_array;
}
```

and result run via valgrind:

```
==2997412== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2997412==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2997412==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 22 frees, 1,216 bytes allocated
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I forgot to account for when a 1 length array is passed into merge_sort.

Comment: @cxtra  Never be defensive about defects.  It slows down your learning.   Accepting and/or upvoting the answer is an implicit thanks.  That said it was my pleasure.

Comment: Your updated code seems to produce incorrect results. And, it has a "use after free" bug. You're doing the `free(left)` and `free(right)` too early. See my answer for details.

Comment: @CraigEstey  Moved `free()` as suggested.  I was playing around with merge when I found this issue exactly the same way you did but forgot to move the `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

I plugged Allan's solution into OP's original code. After some rechecking, I got all zeroes as a result. I couldn't get it to produce a correct output and [AFAICT] it still presented `valgrind` errors

The code has a bug:

1. In `merge_sort`, it does `free(left)` and `free(right)` after their respective loops.
2. But, if the passed length is 1, `merge_sort` will return its original argument.
3. The final call to `merge` used `left_sorted` and `right_sorted`
4. But, these can already be freed if one or more array lengths is 1 (i.e. they could be `left` and/or `right` respectively).
5. This is a "use after free" bug.

---

In the code below, Allan's original `merge_sort` is renamed `merge_sort_allan`.

There are two remedies for `merge_sort`:

1. Move the `free(left)` and `free(right)` to the *bottom* of `merge_sort` This is `merge_sort_allan_fixed` below
2. Eliminate `left` and `right` altogether and pass pointers to the original `arr` to the `merge` calls. This is `merge_sort_craig` below.

---

Here is some updated code with tests. It tests all combinations by using different function names and changing `merge` and `merge_sort` into pointers.

Because there is UB, the test does a `fork` and runs the possibly buggy code in a child to prevent one algorithm from corrupting the heap for another.

At first, I thought OP's `merge` had issues. So, I recoded it to something I know works. But, after the other fix(es), the original `merge` was actually correct. But, I've left in both versions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int *(*merge)(int len_1, int len_2, int *arr1, int *arr2);
int *(*merge_sort)(int len, int *arr);

#define prt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        char buf[100]; \
        int len = sprintf(buf,_fmt); \
        write(1,buf,len); \
    } while (0)

// original
int *
merge_orig(int len_1, int len_2, int *arr1, int *arr2)
{

    // Allocating memory for the output array
    int *result = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (len_1 + len_2));

    // Initialising a pointer for both arrays
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;

    // Sorting the values
    for (int i = 0; i < len_1 + len_2; i++) {
        if ((p1 < len_1) && (p2 >= len_2 || arr1[p1] <= arr2[p2])) {
            result[i] = arr1[p1];
            p1++;
        }
        else {
            result[i] = arr2[p2];
            p2++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int *
merge_craig(int len_1, int len_2, int *arr1, int *arr2)
{

    // Allocating memory for the output array
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int) * (len_1 + len_2));

    // Initialising a pointer for both arrays
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    int i = 0;

    // Sorting the values
    for (;  (p1 < len_1) && (p2 < len_2);  i++) {
        if (arr1[p1] <= arr2[p2])
            result[i] = arr1[p1++];
        else
            result[i] = arr2[p2++];
    }

    for (;  (p1 < len_1);  i++, p1++)
        result[i] = arr1[p1];

    for (;  (p2 < len_2);  i++, p2++)
        result[i] = arr2[p2];

    return result;
}

int *
merge_sort_craig(int len, int *arr)
{
    if (len == 1)
        return arr;

    int midpoint = len / 2;

    int *left_sorted = merge_sort(midpoint, &arr[0]);

    int *right_sorted = merge_sort(len - midpoint, &arr[midpoint]);

    int *sorted_array = merge(midpoint, len - midpoint,
        left_sorted, right_sorted);

    if (midpoint > 1)
        free(left_sorted);
    if (len - midpoint > 1)
        free(right_sorted);

    return sorted_array;
}

int *
merge_sort_allan(int len, int *arr)
{
    if (len == 1)
        return arr;

    int midpoint = len / 2;

// NOTE/BUG: left and right can't be freed here because merge_sort may return
// them as left_sorted and right_sorted
// this is UB (use after free)

    int *left = malloc(sizeof *left * midpoint);
    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
        left[i] = arr[i];
    int *left_sorted = merge_sort(midpoint, left);
    free(left);

    int *right = malloc(sizeof *right * (len - midpoint));
    for (int i = 0; i < len - midpoint; i++)
        right[i] = arr[midpoint + i];
    int *right_sorted = merge_sort(len - midpoint, right);
    free(right);

    int *sorted_array = merge(midpoint, len - midpoint,
        left_sorted, right_sorted);

    if (midpoint > 1)
        free(left_sorted);
    if (len - midpoint > 1)
        free(right_sorted);

    return sorted_array;
}

int *
merge_sort_allan_fixed(int len, int *arr)
{
    if (len == 1)
        return arr;

    int midpoint = len / 2;

    int *left = malloc(sizeof *left * midpoint);
    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
        left[i] = arr[i];
    int *left_sorted = merge_sort(midpoint, left);
#if 0
    free(left);
#endif

    int *right = malloc(sizeof *right * (len - midpoint));
    for (int i = 0; i < len - midpoint; i++)
        right[i] = arr[midpoint + i];
    int *right_sorted = merge_sort(len - midpoint, right);
#if 0
    free(right);
#endif

    int *sorted_array = merge(midpoint, len - midpoint,
        left_sorted, right_sorted);

    if (midpoint > 1)
        free(left_sorted);
    if (len - midpoint > 1)
        free(right_sorted);

#if 1
    free(left);
    free(right);
#endif

    return sorted_array;
}

void
show(int *arr,int len,const char *who)
{

    prt("%s",who);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        prt(" %i", arr[i]);

    prt("\n");
}

void
dotest(const char *m,const char *ms)
{

    prt("\ntest: merge=%s merge_sort=%s\n",m,ms); \

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        return;
    }

    int arr[] = { 10, 3, 7, 5, 11, 16, 23, 14 };
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    show(arr,len,"NOSORT");

    int *result = merge_sort(len, arr);

    show(result,len,"SORTED");

    free(result);
    exit(0);
}

#define TEST(m_,ms_) \
    do { \
        merge = m_; \
        merge_sort = ms_; \
        dotest(#m_,#ms_); \
    } while (0)

int
main(void)
{

    TEST(merge_orig,merge_sort_craig);
    TEST(merge_craig,merge_sort_craig);

    TEST(merge_orig,merge_sort_allan);
    TEST(merge_craig,merge_sort_allan);

    TEST(merge_orig,merge_sort_allan_fixed);
    TEST(merge_craig,merge_sort_allan_fixed);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Compiled normally, here is the program output:

```
test: merge=merge_orig merge_sort=merge_sort_craig
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23

test: merge=merge_craig merge_sort=merge_sort_craig
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23

test: merge=merge_orig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

test: merge=merge_craig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

test: merge=merge_orig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan_fixed
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23

test: merge=merge_craig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan_fixed
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23
```

---

Compiled with `-fsanitize=address`, here is the program output:

```
test: merge=merge_orig merge_sort=merge_sort_craig
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23

test: merge=merge_craig merge_sort=merge_sort_craig
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23

test: merge=merge_orig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
=================================================================
==1940817==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000050 at pc 0x0000004012c4 bp 0x7fffc130a4b0 sp 0x7fffc130a4a0
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000050 thread T0
    #0 0x4012c3 in merge_orig (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x4012c3)
    #1 0x401b5f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401b5f)
    #2 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #3 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #4 0x402513 in dotest (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402513)
    #5 0x402645 in main (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402645)
    #6 0x7f2a42427412 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #7 0x40115d in _start (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40115d)

0x602000000050 is located 0 bytes inside of 4-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000054)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2a426b8840 in __interceptor_free (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xef840)
    #1 0x401a3f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a3f)
    #2 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #3 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #4 0x402513 in dotest (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402513)
    #5 0x402645 in main (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402645)
    #6 0x7f2a42427412 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2a426b8c08 in __interceptor_malloc (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xefc08)
    #1 0x40195a in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40195a)
    #2 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #3 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #4 0x402513 in dotest (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402513)
    #5 0x402645 in main (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402645)
    #6 0x7f2a42427412 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x4012c3) in merge_orig
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 fa fa fa[fd]fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1940817==ABORTING

test: merge=merge_craig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
=================================================================
==1940818==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000050 at pc 0x00000040151c bp 0x7fffc130a4b0 sp 0x7fffc130a4a0
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000050 thread T0
    #0 0x40151b in merge_craig (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40151b)
    #1 0x401b5f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401b5f)
    #2 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #3 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #4 0x402513 in dotest (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402513)
    #5 0x40266a in main (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40266a)
    #6 0x7f2a42427412 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #7 0x40115d in _start (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40115d)

0x602000000050 is located 0 bytes inside of 4-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000054)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2a426b8840 in __interceptor_free (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xef840)
    #1 0x401a3f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a3f)
    #2 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #3 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #4 0x402513 in dotest (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402513)
    #5 0x40266a in main (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40266a)
    #6 0x7f2a42427412 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2a426b8c08 in __interceptor_malloc (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xefc08)
    #1 0x40195a in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40195a)
    #2 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #3 0x401a2f in merge_sort_allan (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x401a2f)
    #4 0x402513 in dotest (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x402513)
    #5 0x40266a in main (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40266a)
    #6 0x7f2a42427412 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free (/tmp/msort/fix3+0x40151b) in merge_craig
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 fa fa fa[fd]fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1940818==ABORTING

test: merge=merge_orig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan_fixed
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23

test: merge=merge_craig merge_sort=merge_sort_allan_fixed
NOSORT 10 3 7 5 11 16 23 14
SORTED 3 5 7 10 11 14 16 23
```